# SCSS file imports using ~ (tilde) is not working in Angular 6

Tags: angular, sass

I have two question regarding `scss` file imports in Angular6

1. Do I need to import my partials in all of my `component.scss` files after having imported it once in global `src/sass/styles.scss`. Shouldn't importing it once be enough?
2. How do I import `SCSS` partials using import shortcut ~ ? All my partials are contained in `src/sass` folder.

This is fine: `@import '../sass/variables';//in app.component.scss`

But this throws error: `@import '~sass/variables'`:

> ERROR in ./src/app/app.component.scss
>       Module build failed: 
>       @import '~sass/variables';
>       ^
>             File to import not found or unreadable: ~sass/variables.
>             in C:\Users\sandeepkumar.g\Desktop\nodebook\tdlr-this\src\app\app.component.scss
>   (line 2, column 1)

`

angular.json:

```
"styles": [
              ...
              "src/sass/styles.scss"
            ],
```

My folder structure:

[image]

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Answering my own question.
It turns out both of these problems are "bug" in Angular 6.

1. Yes, if you want to use any .scss file code in any component.scss, they have to be imported in that component.scss. [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/1253).
2. ~ (Tilda) has stopped working since `Angular6`. [Issue](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/10077). **Use `~src` instead to import scss.**

Comment: Is this still a bug or is it supposed to work like this?

Comment: they changed it. its expected.

Comment: So does this mean that if I have projects folder I need to use tilde like this @import '~projects/ProjectName/src/scss/variables.scss'. Is this angular bug or general tilde feature bug. Or maybe webpack bug?

Comment: I found that this will solve my issue. 
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
              "includePaths": [
                "projects/ProjectName/src/scss"
              ]
            },

and then include files from that folder like this without tilde.
@import 'variables.scss';