# How do I shorten paths to _variables.scss?

Tags: angular, sass

I'm trying to shorten my @import statements. Currently they're all 
`@import "apps/playground/src/app/quiz/styles/variables";`
in all of my SCSS files.

In angular.json I have specified:

```
"styles": [
  "apps/playground/src/app/quiz/styles/styles.scss"
],
"stylePreprocessorOptions": {
  "includePaths": [
    "quiz/styles/"
  ]
},
```

and in styles.scss I have `@import "variables";`

and when I try @import "~variables" in any of the component SCSS files, it doesn't seem to work, it just says "Cannot resolve file '~variables'".

Comment: I have a feeling that this is related to an issue "~ tilde operator unable to path to scss beneath app/src" https://stackoverflow.com/a/51012477/6022352

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In any of your components you should now be able to just `@import 'variables';`, no need for the ~.

Angular will look for styles to import in any of the directories added to the `includePaths`.
The ~ character is used to import from node_modules.

**Edit**: You need to change the path in includePaths to be: `apps/playground/src/app/quiz/styles/`